# Repeat in try catch function after close function in GUI

Tags: database, matlab, if-statement, try-catch, matlab-guide

I have 2 guides. From "Main" guide i called "Search" guide. In search guide have code which check or input value is true if is true got new guide with info. But if input value is false i got popup-message, and still new guide just without info. When i add close function it makes loop and always popup new window and new guide. Please help me. Thanks in advise. Sorry for english.

```
conn = database('baze', 'root', 'root', 'Vendor', 'MYSQL', 'Server', 'localhost', 'PortNumber', 3306);
setdbprefs('datareturnformat','structure');
a = getappdata(0,'numeris');
if iscell(a) && numel(a) == 1
    a = a{1};
end
if ~ischar(a) || isempty(a);
    error('A valid string must be supplied!');
end
sqlquery = ['select vardas, pavarde, laipsnis, pareigos, telefonas, marke, numeris, tarnyba, nuotrauka from info '...
       'where numeris = ' '''' a '''']; 
curs = exec(conn, sqlquery);
setdbprefs('DataReturnFormat','cellarray');
curs = fetch(curs);
if isempty(curs) || ~isstruct(curs) || ~isfield(curs, 'data') || size(curs.data,2) < 7
try
numeris = curs.data{7};
vardas = curs.data{1};
pavarde = curs.data{2};
laipsnis = curs.data{3};
pareigos = curs.data{4};
telefonas = curs.data{5};
marke = curs.data{6};
tarnyba = curs.data{8};
nuotrauka = curs.data(9);
set(handles.edit1,'string',vardas);
set(handles.edit2,'string',pavarde);
set(handles.edit3,'string',laipsnis);
set(handles.edit4,'string',pareigos);
set(handles.edit5,'string',telefonas);
set(handles.edit6,'string',marke);
set(handles.edit7,'string',numeris);
set(handles.edit8,'string',tarnyba);
axes(handles.axes1);
nuotrauka = nuotrauka{1};
jimage = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(typecast(nuotrauka, 'uint8')));
height = jimage.getHeight;
width = jimage.getWidth;
pixels = reshape(typecast(jimage.getData.getDataStorage, 'uint8'), [3,width,height]);
img = cat(3, ...
      transpose(reshape(pixels(3,:,:), [width,height])), ...
      transpose(reshape(pixels(2,:,:), [width,height])), ...
      transpose(reshape(pixels(1,:,:), [width,height])));
imshow(img);
catch
    h = msgbox('Patikrinkite ar teisingai įvesti automobilio numeriai','Įspėjimas','Warn');
    close (paieska)
    return
end
end
close(curs);
close(conn);
```

Comment: I don't see any GUI-related code in the code that you have posted. Please post a [mcve] so that we can help you.

Comment: You don't need to add a return in you catch part. You can replace the if with a while loop and use the ishandle(n) for checking if the window is closed or not. But we need the complete gui code as requested above, before we can completely solve the problem.